# Having trouble opening vi on a remote linux machine in Lion's Terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, vi, osx-lion

I just upgraded to OS X 10.7 (Lion), and when I ssh into a remote linux machine, vi is acting very goofy. Emacs works OK, and ssh'ing into localhost works OK, so I'm guessing there is something odd about the Lion VT100 emulation.

Here's an example of what I'm seeing:

```
$ ssh -l root somelinuxserver
Linux 2.6.29.6.
root@somelinuxserver:~# vi /etc/hosts
reading /etc/hosts
Read /etc/hosts, 4 lines, 45 chars
[a bunch of spaces about this long][]<--Block Cursor Here
```

Any idea what settings I need to change to get this to work?

(I'm an Emacs user on my local machine, but for some bizarre reason, I prefer to edit files on remote servers in vi. If I open emacs, I start typing j to move down a line. It's weird.)

Comment: can you echo $TERM on both local and remote host?

Comment: Both report "xterm-256color".  That does appear to be the problem. Apparently my linux distros interpret that differently than Lion. Switching to plain xterm or vt100, as you suggested, corrected the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try one of:

```
TERM=vt100 vi
TERM=xterm vi
```